# Parquet file larger than memory consumption of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, kedro

I am storing two different pandas DataFrames as parquet files (through [kedro](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).

Both DataFrames have identical dimensions and dtypes (`float32`) before getting written to disk. Also, their memory consumption in RAM is identical:

```
distances_1.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()/1e9
# 3.730033604
```

```
distances_2.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()/1e9
# 3.730033604
```

When persisted as `.parquet` files, the first df results in a file of ~0.89GB and the second file results in a file ~4.5GB.

`distances_1` has many more redundant values than `distances_2` and thus compression might be more effective.

Loading the parquet files from disk into DataFrames results in valid data that is identical to the original DataFrames.

- How can the big size difference between the files be explained?
- For what reasons could the second file be larger than the in-memory data structure?

Comment: Wouldn't it be less confusing to translate RAM into usual units?

Comment: The code provided returns the total memory consumption of the dataframe in GB, right? I thought that would make it easy to compare it to the file sizes.

Comment: I see, it's only that sometimes (like in Windows Explorer) the unit `1GB` means `2^30 Bytes`.

Comment: Is this "many more redundant values" measurable in some way?

Comment: Of course you are right about the GB, the division by 1e9 is just an approximation, but I don't think this is crucial to the issue, is it?

Comment: ...just a tiny detail you may be familiar with: differences in presentation style build a distance between things, compare the relation between *sixteen* and *8*, so it's more a psychological issue. Is there anything new about the actual problem? I mean (2) file representation tend to be larger when references need to be stored. The possibility for optimizations (1) sometimes depend on size (a bitset can be stored in a 64-bit machine word at runtime). Python hashes small numbers. UTF-8 is very efficient for 7-bit charsets. BTW: is there a difference in the origin of the two files?

Answer (score 5):

As you say, the number of unique values can have a very important role in parquet size.

Translating from pandas, two other factors that can have a surprisingly large effect on parquet file size are:

1. pandas indexes, which are saved by default even if they're just auto-assigned;
2. the sorting of your data, which can make a large difference in the run-length encoding parquet sometimes uses.

Shuffled, auto-assigned indices can take a lot of space. If you don't care about the sort order of data on disk, worrying about this can make a significant difference.

Consider four cases of a pandas frame with one column containing the same data in all cases: the rounded squares of the first 2**16 integers. Storing it without indexes in sorted form takes 2.9K; shuffled without the auto-assigned index takes 66K; auto-assigning an index then shuffling takes 475K.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
!mkdir -p /tmp/parquet
d = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.floor(np.sqrt(np.arange(2**16)))})

d.to_parquet("/tmp/parquet/straight.parquet")
d.to_parquet("/tmp/parquet/straight_no_index.parquet", index = False)
d.sample(frac = 1).to_parquet("/tmp/parquet/shuf.parquet")
d.sample(frac = 1).to_parquet("/tmp/parquet/shuf_no_index.parquet", index = False)
```

```sh
ls -lSh /tmp/parquet
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   475K Mar 18 13:39 shuf.parquet
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel    66K Mar 18 13:39 shuf_no_index.parquet
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   3.3K Mar 18 13:39 straight.parquet
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   2.9K Mar 18 13:39 straight_no_index.parquet
```

Comment: Great information, thanks. Writing without indexes makes a tiny difference in my case (much less than 1 promille) but doesn't explain the observed big differences in file sizes at all. I also need to preserve the order of rows (especially when dropping the indexes).

Comment: Do you have an idea why it might be larger on disk than in memory?

Comment: It's hard to think of any without knowing the shape of the data and the engine  As Wolf said, maybe it's something that Python is hashing internally. A couple other possibilities:

Comment: (continuing...) Maybe some of the additional data that parquet can store beyond pandas internals (e.g., the per-page index hints) are out of whack. Maybe somehow the encoding is actually losing space, which can happen; or you have table level information that df.memory_usage(deep=True) isn't measuring. (If your column names, e.g., are each a million characters long, they'll add a lot to file size but not to df.memory_usage(), which doesn't consider them).

Answer (score 1):

From a Kedro point of view this is just calling the PyArrow library `write_table` function doucmented [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html?highlight=write_table#pyarrow.parquet.write_table). Any of these parameters are available by the `save_args` argument in the catalog definition and may be worth playing around with?